# NSDateComponents weekOfYear returns wrong value

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[calendar setFirstWeekday:2];
[calendar setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:1];

NSDateComponents *mockTodayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
mockTodayComponents.day = 28;
mockTodayComponents.month = 12;
mockTodayComponents.year = 2015;
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:mockTodayComponents];
NSDateComponents *c = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear fromDate:date];

NSInteger week = [c weekOfYear];
```

week returns 1 instead of 53 and ofcoaurse the next year weeks enumeration wrong also because of it, what's wrong with my code or it's Apple's bug?

[image: Check start of week 53]

Answer (score 3):

Your `minimumDaysInFirstWeek` is 1. That means that any week that has at least 1 day in the new year is the 1st week of that year. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCalendar/minimumDaysInFirstWeek)

According to [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates):

> There are mutually equivalent descriptions of week 01:
>
> the week with the year's first Thursday in it (the formal ISO
>   definition), the week with 4 January in it, the first week with the
>   majority (four or more) of its days in the starting year, and the week
>   starting with the Monday in the period 29 December – 4 January.