# NSCalendar:components:fromDate: returning bad week of year this week

Tags: ios, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Is currently (Dec 28 2015) producing:

```
Calendar Year: 2015
Week of Year: 1
```

Anybody else seeing this? Know of any workarounds?  Something wrong in my code?

Edit: currentCalendar is Gregorian

Comment: Finally got solution. Your code is correct but it display "1" because its next years 1st week. Please refer [weekofyear returns wrong value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249588/nsdatecomponents-weekofyear-returns-wrong-value) and test it by changing date of device.

Comment: Then it's returning the wrong year, not the wrong week?

Comment: Any week that has at least 1 day in the new year is the 1st week of that year. [NSCalendar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCalendar/minimumDaysInFirstWeek)

Comment: Year is correct but problem is in Week of Year.